# mongo db search operation by inputing some key values and get value

Tags: javascript, mongodb

i have following data in the database

```
db.report.insert({ "_id" : ObjectId("54d70"), "server" : { "timestamp" : "Thu Feb 12 07:14:19 2015", "person" : "lali", "candidate" : [  {  "isno" : "63",  "id" : "4c:64:33:e9" } ], "id" :"24" } })
db.report.insert({ "_id" : ObjectId("5471"), "server" : { "timestamp" : "Thu Feb 12 07:14:39 2015", "person" : "lali", "candidate" : [  {  "isno" : "4",  "id" : "4c:64:33:e9" } ], "id" : "24" } })
db.report.insert({ "_id" : ObjectId("5472"), "server" : { "timestamp" : "Thu Feb 12 07:14:09 2015", "person" : "lali", "candidate" : [  {  "isno" : "6",  "id" : "4c:64:33:e9" } ], "id" : "24" } })
```

by inputing the values `timestamp ''Thu Feb 12 07:14:19 2015' ,id 4c:64:33:e9 and id :24` i need to extract isno key values `63 ,4 and 6` how it is possible with mongo db

Comment: Can you explain more what mean by `i need to extract isno key values 63 ,4 and 6 `  you want find this values ?

Comment: yes i need to find that values

Comment: if you don't mind can you post your expected output

Comment: expected output as {"isno" : "63"} {"isno" : "4"}{"isno" : "6"} like that

Comment: Is `candidate` an array that never grows beyond one element? It's length one in all three example documents.

Comment: yes ur correct....actually the the output will be {"isno" : "63"} or  {"isno" : "4"} or {"isno" : "6"} its length is one as u said....